# How do i add a security group as an inbound rule to another security group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-security-group, bastion-host

I have a Terraform codebase which deploys a private EKS cluster, a bastion host and other AWS services. I have also added a few security groups to the in Terraform. One of the security groups allows inbound traffic from my Home IP to the bastion host so that i can SSH onto that node. This security group is called `bastionSG`, and that works fine also.

However, initially I am unable to run kubectl from my bastion host, which is the node I use to carry out my kubernetes development on against the EKS cluster nodes. The reason is because my EKS cluster is a private and only allows communication from nodes in the same VPC and i need to add a security group that allows the communication from my bastion host to the `cluster control plane` which is where my security group bastionSG comes in.

So my routine now is once Terraform deploys everything, I then find the automatic generated EKS security group and add my `bastionSG` as an inbound rule to it through the AWS Console (UI) as shown in the image below.

[image]

I would like to NOT have to do this through the UI, as i am already using Terraform to deploy my entire infrastructure.

I know i can query an existing security group like this

```
data "aws_security_group" "selectedSG" {
  id = var.security_group_id
}
```

In this case, lets say `selectedSG` is the security group creared by EKS once terraform is completed the apply process. I would like to then add an inbound rule of `bastionSG` to it without it ovewriting the others it's added automatically.

**UPDATE: > EKS NODE GROUP**

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "flmd_node_group" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  node_group_name = var.node_group_name
  node_role_arn   = var.node_pool_role_arn
  subnet_ids      = [var.flmd_private_subnet_id]
  instance_types = ["t2.small"]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 3
    min_size     = 3
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  remote_access {
    ec2_ssh_key = "MyPemFile"
    source_security_group_ids = [
      var.allow_tls_id,
      var.allow_http_id, 
      var.allow_ssh_id,
      var.bastionSG_id
     ]
  }

  tags = {
    "Name" = "flmd-eks-node"
  }
}
```

As shown above, the EKS node group has the bastionSG security group in it. which i expect to allow the connection from my bastion host to the EKS control plane.

**EKS Cluster**

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "flmd_cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids =[var.flmd_private_subnet_id, var.flmd_public_subnet_id, var.flmd_public_subnet_2_id]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access = false
    security_group_ids = [ var.bastionSG_id]
  }
}
```

`bastionSG_id` is an output of the security group created below which is passed into the code above as a variable.

**BastionSG security group**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "bastionSG" {
  name        = "Home to bastion"
  description = "Allow SSH - Home to Bastion"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description      = "Home to bastion"
    from_port        = 22
    to_port          = 22
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [<MY HOME IP address>]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Home to bastion"
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be possible, but without any code except the data source it's hard to make a valid assumption.

Comment: What is your current code and why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin updated with code

Comment: @MarkoE updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simpler solution.

Query AWS using terraform data attribute, get the id of the security group then use that to create security_group_rule in terraform with the inbound rule that is required.

Comment: can you provide more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with creating first of all a public security group.

```
################################################################################
# Create the Security Group
################################################################################
resource "aws_security_group" "public" {
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  name        = format("${var.name}-${var.public_security_group_suffix}-SG")
  description = format("${var.name}-${var.public_security_group_suffix}-SG")
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.public_security_group_ingress
    content {
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(ingress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      from_port        = lookup(ingress.value, "from_port", 0)
      to_port          = lookup(ingress.value, "to_port", 0)
      protocol         = lookup(ingress.value, "protocol", "-1")
    }
  }
  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = var.public_security_group_egress
    content {
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(egress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(egress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      from_port        = lookup(egress.value, "from_port", 0)
      to_port          = lookup(egress.value, "to_port", 0)
      protocol         = lookup(egress.value, "protocol", "-1")
    }
  }
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.public_security_group_suffix}-SG",
      )
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

Now creating a private security group, making inbound from the public security group, and outbound to the elasticache and rds security group.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "private" {
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  name        = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-SG")
  description = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-SG")

  ingress {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.public.id]
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
  }
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.private_security_group_ingress
    content {
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(ingress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      from_port        = lookup(ingress.value, "from_port", 0)
      to_port          = lookup(ingress.value, "to_port", 0)
      protocol         = lookup(ingress.value, "protocol", "-1")
    }
  }
  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = var.private_security_group_egress
    content {
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(egress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(egress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      from_port        = lookup(egress.value, "from_port", 0)
      to_port          = lookup(egress.value, "to_port", 0)
      protocol         = lookup(egress.value, "protocol", "-1")
    }
  }
  egress {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.elsaticache_private.id] # it communciates via network interfaces
    from_port       = 6379                                        # redis port
    to_port         = 6379
    protocol        = "tcp"
  }
  egress {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.rds_mysql_private.id]
    from_port       = 3306
    to_port         = 3306
    protocol        = "tcp"
  }
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-SG"
      )
    },
    var.tags,
  )
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.elsaticache_private, aws_security_group.rds_mysql_private]
}
```

Creating just an egress rule in elasticache security group, and adding one more rule for ingress from the private security group as it resolves the dependency. The same goes for the RDS Security group.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elsaticache_private" {
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  name        = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-elasticache-SG")
  description = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-elasticache-SG")
  egress {
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
  }
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.public_security_group_suffix}-elasticache-SG",
      )
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "elsaticache_private_rule" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 6379 # redis port
  to_port                  = 6379
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.private.id
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.elsaticache_private.id
  depends_on               = [aws_security_group.private]
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds_mysql_private" {
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  name        = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-rds-mysql-SG")
  description = format("${var.name}-${var.private_security_group_suffix}-rds-mysql-SG")
  egress {
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
  }
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.public_security_group_suffix}-rds-mysql-SG",
      )
    },
    var.tags,
  )
}
```

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rds_mysql_private_rule" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 3306 # mysql / aurora port
  to_port                  = 3306
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.private.id
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.rds_mysql_private.id
  depends_on               = [aws_security_group.private]
}
```